# Prevalidation on create plugin

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I've written a plugin with the following configuration:

[image]

I'm simply trying to set one `datetime` field to equal another `datetime` field:

```
 IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
            IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;

            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                // Obtain the target entity from the input parmameters.
                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
                try
                {
                    if (entity.LogicalName == "list" && entity.Attributes["gbs_lastusedonoriginal"] != null)
                    {
                        entity.Attributes["lastusedon"] = entity.Attributes["gbs_lastusedonoriginal"];
                        service.Update(entity);
                    }
                }
                catch (FaultException ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occured in the plug-in.", ex);
                }

            }
```

The exception I get is:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault,
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: An error occured in the
>   plug-in.Detail:  
>   -2147220891   
>       
>         OperationStatus
>         0
>       
>       
>         SubErrorCode
>         -2146233088
>             An error occured in the plug-in.
>   2015-01-15T05:34:00.1772929Z
>
> [PreValidationMarketingList.Plugins:
>   PreValidationMarketingList.Plugins.PreValidateMarketingListCreate]
>   [5454a088-749c-e411-b3df-6c3be5a83130: PreValidateMarketingListCreate]
>
> Entered
>   PreValidationMarketingList.Plugins.PreValidateMarketingListCreate.Execute(),
>   Correlation Id: 6d3ed105-f9c4-4006-9c80-08abd97c0140, Initiating User:
>   5e1b0493-d07b-e411-b592-f0921c199288
>   PreValidationMarketingList.Plugins.PreValidateMarketingListCreate is
>   firing for Entity: list, Message: Create, Correlation Id:
>   6d3ed105-f9c4-4006-9c80-08abd97c0140, Initiating User:
>   5e1b0493-d07b-e411-b592-f0921c199288 Exiting
>   PreValidationMarketingList.Plugins.PreValidateMarketingListCreate.Execute(),
>   Correlation Id: 6d3ed105-f9c4-4006-9c80-08abd97c0140, Initiating User:
>   5e1b0493-d07b-e411-b592-f0921c199288

What am I doing wrong?**In crm 2013 how do I set one field to equal another field if both of them are datetimes?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `Update` in this plugin because you haven't created and saved the record you are trying to update.

First, move this to pre-operation, not pre-validation. It's a nit but pre-op is really the appropriate place since setting `lastusedon` is not required for validation on Create of `list`.

I've reworked your code to do some additional checks:

```
        IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;
        IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            // Obtain the target entity from the input parmameters.
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
            try
            {
                if (entity.LogicalName == "list" && entity.Attributes.Contains("gbs_lastusedonoriginal") && entity["gbs_lastusedonoriginal"] != null)
                {
                    if (entity.Attributes.Contains("lastusedon") )
                        entity.Attributes["lastusedon"] = entity.Attributes["gbs_lastusedonoriginal"];
                    else entity.Attributes.Add("lastusedon", entity.Attributes["gbs_lastusedonoriginal"];                        
                }
            }
            catch (FaultException ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occured in the plug-in.", ex);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Good answer although I think you should explain a bit more explicitly why the field is still getting updated even though you have removed the Update call.

Comment: See my post and links to the MSDN page

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! isnt it enough to do just this: entity["gbs_lastusedonoriginal"] != null rather than both of these:entity.Attributes.Contains("gbs_lastusedonoriginal") && entity["gbs_lastusedonoriginal"] != null

Comment: Have to use both entity.Attributes.Contains("gbs_lastusedonoriginal") && entity["gbs_lastusedonoriginal"] != null -- otherwise you'll get an error if the entity doesn't have that attribute

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327941.aspx) link on MSDN. In the Pre-Event, the record is not yet saved in the SQL database. You can modify the Entity object from the InputParameters. After the pre-event plugin the record will be created with your modified attributes.

The main difference between Pre-validation and Pre-operation is that the Pre-operation stage is executed within the database transaction while Pre-validation not. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327941.aspx#bkmk_PipelineStages) for more information.